# Asymptotic growth rate of running time of BinarySearch

Tags: algorithm, search

In the following pseudo code for binarySearch

```
myfunction(A[1],A[2]..A[n]:array of ints,x:positive integer){
  i = 1
  j = n
 while i<=j do 
     k=floor( (i+j)/2)
    if (x==A[k])
      return k;
    else if (x<A[k])
      j=k-1
    else
      i=k+1
 return -1 
  }
```

Why is this inequality true `j-i+1 <= n / 2^t` where `t` is the number of iterations. All I get is that `n /2^t` with t increasing if `n/2^t =1` then t will be the total number of iterations but the Left handed side : `i-j+1` I don't get how we connect these statements to make inequality.What is the logic behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j-i+1` is at any point in time the number of values still to consider. It is clear that the inequality holds at the beginning: `n-1+1 = n / 2^0`.

Now with each iteration you approximately half the interval to be searched. A careful analysis of the different cases shows the interval is even reduced a bit more than that. So each iteration gives you at least another factor of 1/2 for the interval size.

I will just do one case and leave the other three as exercise for you.
Assume `j-i+1` is equal to `s` and assume `s` is an odd number. Then `i+j` is even and `k=(i+j)/2` points exactly to the middle element leaving `(s-1)/2` elements to the left of it and to the right of it. Lets assume now `x < A[k]` so that we will set `j` to `k-1`. The new value of `j-i+1` is therefore `k-1-i+1 = k-i = (s-1)/2 < s/2`.